# I keep getting a comparison between number and nil when trying to sort a table by myself

Tags: sorting, lua, numbers, compare, null

```
taula = {};

function randomNumber()
  return math.random(100);
end

function startArray()
    for x=0, 10 do
        taula[x]=randomNumber();
    end
end

function printArray()
    for i=0,#taula do
        print(taula[i]);
    end
end

function organizeArray()
   for i=0,#taula do
        for j=1,#taula do
            if taula[i]>taula[j] then
                tmp = taula[j];
                taula[j]=taula[i];
                taula[i]=taula[tmp];
            end
        end
    end
end

startArray()
organizeArray()
printArray()
```

This is not working! The initial idea is to have printed the table declared as 'taula' but in the function organizeArray() there is a problem in the if, it says I compare a number with a nil value when I have both j and i variables declared. I need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referencing `tala[tmp]` instead of `tmp` (at line 27) when you're shuffling the array around. That's what's causing the bug.

A few pointers:

- You're using globals for everything. This can cause headaches later on, when globals collide (i.e tmp could be set to something, and you do something with it). See: [Local Variables and Blocks](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html)
- Using `randomNumber()` makes your code kind of obscure, since randomNumber is just an alias for `math.random(100)`.
- Lua starts at `1`, not `0`. You can start at `0`, but this is just something to keep in mind. `#table` will not count the index `0`.
- When asking questions, please give the full error message -- this'll let us look at the code without having to run it ourselves :)
- You can put `print(x)` in your code, so you can see what's happening. This'll help you find bugs, since you know whats going on.

Comment: I'm sorry I took this long to answer. Thanks a lot for the help! I've improved my coding skills a lot and really this chunk of code looks very clunky to me now. Again, thanks for taking the time to answer :)